# Objective-C: how to allocate array of GLuint

Tags: iphone, arrays, opengl-es

I have an array of GLuint with fixed size:

```
GLuint textures[10];
```

Now I need to set a size of array dynamically. I wrote something like this:

*.h:

```
GLuint *textures;
```

*.m:

```
textures = malloc(N * sizeof(GLuint));
```

where N - needed size.

Then it used like this:

```
glGenTextures(N, &textures[0]);
// load texture from image

-(GLuint)getTexture:(int)index{
    return textures[index];
}
```

I used the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150650/is-it-ok-to-use-classic-malloc-free-in-objective-c-iphone-apps), but program fell in runtime. How to fix this?

Program is written on Objective-C and uses OpenGL ES.

Comment: Stopped working, wrote: "Running pass 'Combine redundant instructions' on function '@glvmInterpretFPTransformFour9'". Fixed in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this issue.

This code is valid but seems like not working. This problem is described [here](http://blog.thedailyanvil.com/?p=289), but it's not so clear.

The solution that works for me is to create separate class with GLuint property:

```
@interface Texture : NSObject
    GLuint texture;
@end

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) GLuint texture;
```

Then we can create NSMutableArray of Textures:

```
NSMutableArray *textures;
```

In *.m file we should fill our array:

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    Texture *t = [[Texture alloc] init];
    t.texture = i;
    GLuint l = t.texture;
    [textures addObject:t];
    glGenTextures(1, &l);
}
```

If you use other array(s) with textures you have to shift GLuint indexes, e.g.:

```
t.texture = i+M;
```

where M - size of earlier used array of GLuint's.

Then getTexture will be rewritten as following:

```
-(GLuint)getTexture:(int)index{
    return textures[index].texture;
}
```

I am not excited with this approach but it's a single one I make work.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the value of N to 10, then the behavior of the two methods will be identical. You should therefore look for the reason for the failure in different places.

Answer (score 0):

void glGenTextures( GLsizei     n,
    GLuint *    textures);

accepts an array of unsigned ints, and it looks like you are passing a pointer to the first element in the array, which I think is not what you want to do or what the function accepts

maybe just try

glGenTextures(N, textures);

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the behavior of this code is equal to provided.