# GLDrawElements Crashing Program

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I am trying to render some vertices to an Open GL ES window. My program keeps crashing on the GLDrawElements command. I am trying to pass some VBOs for the vertices "bindPosition", "bindNorml" and "Index" of type GLFloat.

Here is a link to my rendering method:

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {

glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

glClearColor(0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

GLKMatrix4 modelView = GLKMatrix4Make(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -10, -30, 1);
GLKMatrix4 projectionView = GLKMatrix4Make(3.6213202476501465, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4142136573791504, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0020020008087158, -1, 0, -24.142135620117188, 28.05805778503418, 30);

// Upload Transforms
glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewMatrixUniform, 1, 0, modelView.m);
glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewProjMatrixUniform, 1, 0, projectionView.m);

// Upload Bones
glUniformMatrix4fv(_bonesUniform, 1, 0, bones);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bindPositionBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(_VertexPositionAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(bindPosition), 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bindNormalBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(_VertexNormalAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(bindNormal), 0);


// 3
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(Index)/sizeof(Index[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

[_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Setting up VBOS:

```
- (void)setupVBOs {

glGenBuffers(1, &_bindPositionBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bindPositionBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bindPosition), bindPosition, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &_bindNormalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bindNormalBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bindNormal), bindNormal, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Index), Index, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}
```

Compiling Shaders:

```
- (void)compileShaders {

// 1
GLuint vertexShader = [self compileShader:@"SimpleVertex" withType:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
GLuint fragmentShader = [self compileShader:@"SimpleFragment" withType:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

// 2
GLuint programHandle = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(programHandle);

// 3
GLint linkSuccess;
glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkSuccess);
if (linkSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
    GLchar messages[256];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
    NSString *messageString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:messages];
    NSLog(@"%@", messageString);
    exit(1);
}

// 4
glUseProgram(programHandle);

// 5    
// Uniform Locations
_bonesUniform               = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Bones[0]");
_modelViewMatrixUniform     = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "ModelViewMatrix");
_modelViewProjMatrixUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "ModelViewProjMatrix");
_textureUniform             = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Texture");

// Attribute Locations
_VertexBoneWeightAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "VertexBoneWeight");
_VertexBoneIDAttribute     = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "VertexBoneID");
_VertexTexCoord0Attribute  = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "VertexTexCoord0");
_VertexNormalAttribute     = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "VertexNormal");
_VertexPositionAttribute   = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "VertexPosition");    

// Enable vertex pointers
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_VertexBoneWeightAttribute);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_VertexBoneIDAttribute);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_VertexTexCoord0Attribute);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_VertexNormalAttribute);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_VertexPositionAttribute);

}
```

Here is a link to my shaders:

```
attribute vec3 VertexPosition;
attribute vec3 VertexNormal;
attribute vec2 VertexTexCoord0;
attribute vec4 VertexBoneID;
attribute vec4 VertexBoneWeight;


uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjMatrix;

uniform vec4 Bones[222];


varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec2 TexCoord0;


void main(void)
{
TexCoord0 = VertexTexCoord0;

// Build 4x3 skinning matrix.
vec4 r0 = Bones[int(VertexBoneID.x) * 3 + 0] * VertexBoneWeight.x;
vec4 r1 = Bones[int(VertexBoneID.x) * 3 + 1] * VertexBoneWeight.x;
vec4 r2 = Bones[int(VertexBoneID.x) * 3 + 2] * VertexBoneWeight.x;

r0 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.y) * 3 + 0] * VertexBoneWeight.y;
r1 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.y) * 3 + 1] * VertexBoneWeight.y;
r2 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.y) * 3 + 2] * VertexBoneWeight.y;

r0 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.z) * 3 + 0] * VertexBoneWeight.z;
r1 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.z) * 3 + 1] * VertexBoneWeight.z;
r2 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.z) * 3 + 2] * VertexBoneWeight.z;

r0 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.w) * 3 + 0] * VertexBoneWeight.w;
r1 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.w) * 3 + 1] * VertexBoneWeight.w;
r2 += Bones[int(VertexBoneID.w) * 3 + 2] * VertexBoneWeight.w;

// Skin and transform position.
float px = dot(r0, vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0));
float py = dot(r1, vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0));
float pz = dot(r2, vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0));

gl_Position = ModelViewProjMatrix * vec4(px, py, pz, 1.0);

/*  Skin and transform normal into view-space. We assume that the modelview matrix
 doesn't contain a scale. Should pass pass in the inverse-transpose really. */
float nx = dot(r0, vec4(VertexNormal, 0.0));
float ny = dot(r1, vec4(VertexNormal, 0.0));
float nz = dot(r2, vec4(VertexNormal, 0.0));

Normal = normalize((ModelViewMatrix * vec4(nx, ny, nz, 0.0)).xyz);
}
```

Frag Shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif


uniform sampler2D Texture;


varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec2 TexCoord0;


void main(void)
{
// Ambient term.
vec3 lighting = vec3(0.5,0.5,0.5) * 0.7;

/*  Very cheap lighting. Three directional lights, one shining slighting upwards to     illuminate
 underneath the chin, and then one each shining from the left and right. Light directional
 are in view-space and follow the camera rotation by default. */
lighting += dot(Normal, normalize(vec3( 0.0, -0.2, 0.8))) * vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.6) * 0.6;      // Shines forwards and slightly upwards.
lighting += dot(Normal, normalize(vec3(-0.8,  0.4, 0.8))) * vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.6) * 0.4;      // Shines forwards and from left to right.
lighting += dot(Normal, normalize(vec3( 0.8,  0.4, 0.8))) * vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.6) * 0.4;      // Shines forwards and from right to left.

//gl_FragColor = vec4(Normal * 0.5 + vec3(0.5), 1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(Texture, TexCoord0).xyz * lighting, 1.0);
}
```

Can anyone see anything in my render method which i have done wrong?

Comment: The error message is : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)

Comment: Maybe the code you posted is incomplete but I don't seem to see where you are calling glBufferData.  As it appears to me, it seems the problem is that you are not actually binding any data to OpenGL.  You must call glBufferData in order to bind data to a Vertex Attribute Pointer.

Comment: Hello, I have included some more code from my program

Answer (score 1):

If you bind GLFloat values to your GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, that could be a problem. You should bind GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT. 
 http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml

Answer (score 0):

When binding the index buffer in your render method, you should use `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` instead of `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I have made the change you suggested but am still experiencing the same issue

Comment: The fifth argument to `glVertexAttribPointer` should be the stride, in bytes, between one vertex and the next vertex.  You can also pass 0 for tightly-packed attributes.  I'm not sure what your `bindPosition` variable is, but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `glDrawElements` doesn't look to be correct. Nor does your call to `glBufferData`.

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Index), Index, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(Index)/sizeof(Index[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

It looks like you're passing a struct to `glBufferData` rather than an array of indices. Unless your parameter is called `Index` but it doesn't seem that way due to how you're using it. You need to build an array of vertex indices and pass this in to tell the GPU what you want to draw.

The second parameter to `glDrawElement` should be the number of elements you want to render. I had a similar problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157957/opengl-es-interleaving-vertex-buffer-object) which someone helpfully pointed out I was making the same mistake. Hopefully it will be helpful to you too.