# How to release a struct that was passed by reference to c code and its member was malloc'ed there?

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm getting "malloc: *** error for object 0xbfffe160: pointer being freed was not allocated" when trying to free memory (in objective-c code) of an object that was allocated inside c function. This C function creates and returns binary data packet that is used as NSData later. Here's my obj-c code part where I'm creating struct variable and passing it by reference to C function:

```
MyPacket packetRef;
allocAuthentificationCodePacket(&packetRef);

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:packetRef.bytes length:packetRef.packet->packetSize];
free(&packetRef); // getting error
```

Everything work fine, except I'm trying to release the memory because the data should be retained by NSData variable. The C functions performs calloc inside itself, so I should somehow to release that memory:

```
packetRef->bytes = calloc(1, sizeof(*packetRef));
```

Here's are my structs for storing binary data:

```
typedef struct {

  uint8_t packetType;
  uint16_t packetBody;

} MyStruct;
```

and another struct:

```
typedef union {

  const uint8_t *bytes; 
  MyStruct *packet;

} MyPacket;
```

How should I free the memory? The error I'm getting is not crash, it just a message in debug console when running unit tests.

**UPDATE**. Tried to release "bytes" struct member but getting the same error message:

```
free(&packetRef.bytes);
```

**UPDATE2**. Thanks, the suggested way did worked and malloc error message disappeared from console:

```
free(packetRef.bytes);
```

However, getting a warning in Xcode "Passing 'const uint8_t *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers". I'm using Apple LLVM 4.1 compiler. C function resides in separate file and only a header is included because Android guys will have to reuse it.

**UPDATE3**. Thanks to @simonc and @nos who have pointed out the struct member "bytes" has const. The warning has disappeared after removing const. The initial idea of using const was to protect "bytes" from modification.

Comment: I dont think calloc convenient way to work with memory in ObjC. Please have a look at http://memo.tv/archive/memory_management_with_objective_c_cocoa_iphone and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150650/is-it-ok-to-use-classic-malloc-free-in-objective-c-iphone-apps

Comment: @Whity: That's an unhelpful link.  You cannot use ARC or GC to track data that is not contained in Objective-C objects, and the asker is working with data created in C functions.  The second link also contradicts what you are saying.

Comment: To your update: And again wrong. You're trying to free the pointer (which again is a stack variable). You have to free the data pointed to by the pointer (Hint: remove the `&` and see what happens). As a side note you should really delve a little deeper into the fundamentals about pointers and dynamic memory management.

Comment: Idea was to show other ways to work with memory.

Comment: @Whity: But there aren't necessarily other ways to work with memory here.  It's not allocated in an Objective C file so you can't use Objective C methods to allocate it.

Comment: I thought that guy need some more practice with memory management. For example calloc in this case is useless. alloc would be enough.

Comment: @Whity: I feel like a broken record -- you can't call `alloc` from a C file, and you can't use it to allocate things that aren't Objective-C objects.  Stop suggesting `alloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *always wrong.*  (Hint: It's almost always wrong to put `&` inside of `free()`.)

```
MyPacket packetRef;
...
free(&packetRef); // getting error
```

It doesn't matter what `MyPacket` is -- it has automatic storage duration, i.e., the compiler automatically allocates storage and frees it when the function exits.

Do not `free()` something unless it came from `malloc()` (or `calloc()`, etc.)

Since `packetRef.bytes`  was allocated with `calloc()`, you can `free()` that instead.

```
MyPacket packetRef;
allocAuthentificationCodePacket(&packetRef);
...
free(packetRef.bytes);
```

#### Update

If the function that you call, `allocAuthentificationCodePacket`, contains the code:

```
packetRef->bytes = calloc(1, sizeof(*packetRef));
```

And if the `bytes` field has type `const uint8_t *`, then something is wrong.

1. Perhaps your code is wrong, and you are supposed to call some function to free the packet rather than freeing it yourself.
2. Perhaps the type of the `bytes` field is wrong, and should be `uint8_t *` instead of `const uint8_t *`.
3. Perhaps `allocAuthentificationCodePacket` is wrong.

Who knows?  It's not wrong enough to crash, but it *is* a problem.

#### Footnote

There are no references in C.  `&x` is "address of x", not "reference to x".

Let's consider the following code:

```
char *x = malloc(10);
free(x);
```

When people talk about this code, they will say something like "`x` is allocated on the heap", but that's not technically correct, `x` is allocated on the stack and contains the address of 10 bytes on the heap.  Likewise, the line `free(x)` does not actually free `x`, it frees the memory which `x` points to.

So when someone tells you, "don't forget to free `x`", you know they actually mean "don't forget to free the memory which the value contained in `x` points to".  People are sloppy with terminology but computers aren't.

Comment: But there's a calloc inside C function that allocates space for packetRef->bytes. So, I don't need to release that?

Comment: @Centurion: Think about it this way: the C function allocates memory, and stores a pointer to that memory in `packetRef.bytes`.  The actual variable, `packetRef.bytes`, has automatic storage duration and does not need to be freed.  However, it contains a pointer to a region of memory which must be freed.

Comment: Thanks, but then getting a warning. Please see UPDATE2.

Comment: @Centurion Your `bytes` member is const. Don't make it const if you intend to free it.

Answer (score 2):

`packetRef` is a stack variable in your example with `packetRef->bytes` heap allocated.  You should therefore call `free(packetRef.bytes)`

Since you allocate the memory inside a function - `allocAuthentificationCodePacket` - you may want to create another function to free the memory

```
void freePacket(MyPacket* packet)
{
    free(packet->bytes);
}
```

Comment: I can't use packet->bytes because compiler gives me error "Member reference type is not pointer. Maybe you meant to use "."?". If I use "free(packet.bytes)" then I get a warning "Passing 'const uint8_t *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers".

Comment: @Centurion: Did you actually copy and paste the entire `freePacket` function?  Because it sounds like you didn't.  You shouldn't be getting those errors if you copied and pasted the entire function.

Comment: C function resides in separate c file and only a header is imported with function declaration. Because Android guys will try to reuse that.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks. The initial idea was to secure "bytes" from modification and the structs are used both for data read and for data write (same packets).