# How to allocate memory for array in function and then return a pointer to it in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c++11

I have a function which transforms a `std::vector` into `NSMutableArray`. I have handled all the bridging actions, but there is one thing which I am not able to do. I want to make an `NSMutableArray` in that function, then copy the vector elements in that array, and then return  pointer to it's beginning. In C++ I would simply allocate some necessary memory, use it and return the pointer to it's beginning, how to do the same for Objective-C ?

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150650/is-it-ok-to-use-classic-malloc-free-in-objective-c-iphone-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've created the `NSMutableArray`, you just return it. The thing you're returning *is* a pointer. You "allocated some necessary memory" when you called `[NSMutableArray alloc]` (either directly or indirectly).

Remember that `NSArray` is not guaranteed to by contiguous memory, so "a pointer to its beginning" isn't really meaningful. You want a pointer to the object, and that's exactly what you have. Just return it.